# Reading input using getchar_unlocked()

Tags: c

I have learnt that using `getchar_unlocked` is fast way of reading input. I have seen the code to read at many places but was unable to understand. Can anyone please help me understand how to read using `getchar_unlocked` ?
Thanks in Advance.

```
void scanint(int &x)
{
 register int c = getchar_unlocked();
 x = 0;
 for(;(c<48 || c>57);c = getchar_unlocked())
  ;
 for(;c>47 && c<58;c = getchar_unlocked()) 
 {
   x = (x<<1) + (x<<3) + c - 48;
 }
}
```

I have seen many other codes as well. I dont particularly understand the purpose of shifting the number. Any help regarding that is appreciated

Comment: It can be faster using `(c&15)` instead of `c - 48`.

Answer (score 5):

`getch_lock` reads a character at a time. here in the given code we are trying to read an integer. the purpose of first `for` loop is to read digit character if any present and neglect it. The second `for` loop reads a char which must be digit and performs
   `n=n*10+c`
As C is in Ascii we have subtracted 48 ie Ascii code of `'0'` . To make code faster instead of using multiplication shift is used.
`n*10=n*(8+2)=n*8+n*2=n<<3+n<<1`

Answer (score 1):

`getchar_unlocked()` is like `getchar()` except that it does not check for multi-thread locks.

So, it is faster, but it is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have the wrong idea of the purpose of [`getchar_unlocked()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/getchar_unlocked/). Really.

When doing single-character I/O from a human user, it's fantastically hard to believe that you need to focus on being "fast", since the human will be very slow.

The function you included looks like it's reading an integer using `getchar_fast()`, and is written in a pretty horrible style. It certainly doesn't look like part of a solution to anything in particular. It's also totally broken in its handling of the `x` pointer variable.

In short, your question is not very clear.

Comment: Yeah it is to read integer.I have seen many other codes as well. I dont particularly understand the purpose of shifting the number. Any help regarding that is appreciated.
Can u give an idea of getchar_fast. Never heard of it before.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. I've got 2 lessons here. First - mathematics: The shifting has its purpose. It's fast multiplication by 10: x * 10 = x * (2 + 8) = 2*x + 8*x = (x << 1) + (x << 3). Lesson 2 - computer usage: standard input doesn't mean "input from keyboard". It could be some terabyte large file from SSD piped to our process. Still no need to worry about I/O performance?

Comment: @TomaszGandor I really don't think you want to do a function call per character if your aim is fast input of terabytes of data, no. And I also think strength-reducing multiplication to shift+add is not very relevant on any modern computer. Integer multiply is cheap. And if it isn't, that's the optimizer's job to fix.